# Sending grep data iteratively using curl for output of tail -f

Tags: shell, unix, curl, grep

I am using grep to extract data from a log file. The log file is dynamically updating new rows. and I need to send the grepped data to a REST endpoint using curl. This can be done easily for a static file but cannot find a solution fo a running log file. How can I realize this situation?

eg: `tail -f | grep "<string>" > ~/<fileName>.log`

The above can put the data in a file. Need to send it using a POST curl.

Maybe using a function like

```
send_data(){
    curl -s -k -X POST –header Content-Type: application/json’ \
        –header ‘Accept: application/json’ \
        “http://${HOST}${PORT}/v1/notify” \
        -d $1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `tail -f | grep "<string>" > ~/<fileName>.log` is working for you then you could do:

```
tail -f file | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 grep "<string>" | xargs -n 1 -d $'\n' curl ...
```

or:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    curl ... "$line"
done < <(tail -f file | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 grep "<string>")
```